# What does it mean to flush the output in competitive programming?

Tags: c++, flush

I am currently giving codechef long challenge and there they are asking to flush the output after printing each line. How to use flush in cpp and how does this affect the time limit if I am not using flush?
Currently I am using this code-

```
cout<<z<<" "<<endl;
cout.flush();
```

Comment: You're flushing twice: `<< std::endl` is equivalent to `<< '\n' << std::flush`.

Answer (score 3):

Flushing makes output slower, because it cannot buffer 2 lines and output them at once.

However, `std::endl` already flushes for you.

You can send an endline *without* flushing by printing `'\n'`.

As an aside, you might want to `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` to improve io speed if you aren't using C based IO.

Comment: Flushing *might* make output slower. It could also have no effect on the performance, because the receiving system is fast enough to consume the unbuffered output.

Comment: @Caleth I guess that is possible, but there aren't many teletype machines left.